# Hi, i have a litle project. I need to get information about t the draw of poker games

Tags: c#

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            var resuult = ReaderHelper.ReadFromFile(@"C:\Users\xalva\source\repos\pokerstars\Aletta.txt");
            Console.WriteLine(resuult);
            Reader reader = new Reader(resuult, 0);

        }

    }

static class ReaderHelper
    {
        public static string ReadFromFile(string filePath)
        {
            string pokerText;
            using (FileStream pokerHand = File.OpenRead(filePath))
            {
                byte[] array = new byte[pokerHand.Length];
                pokerHand.Read(array, 0, array.Length);
                pokerText = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(array);

            }
            return pokerText;

        }


 public  class Reader
    {


        static int Cursor { get; set; }
        static string Buffer { get; set; }
        public Reader(string buffer, int cursor)
        {
            Cursor = cursor;
            Buffer = buffer;
        }
```

I have a little project where i have to get some information from text file about draw of poker hands.
In class ReaderHelper I get information from a text file, then I create an object of the Reader class and get null in the Buffer. Why so?(It's not all code)

Comment: idk, but it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `File.ReadAllText("[...]")` to read text from a file:

```
 static void Main()
 {
     var result = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\xalva\source\repos\pokerstars\Aletta.txt");
     Console.WriteLine(result);
     Reader reader = new Reader(result, 0);
 }
```

or you can use a `StreamReader` object, if you want to use streams, to read text:

```
public static string ReadFromFile(string filePath)
{
    string pokerText;
    using (FileStream pokerHand = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pokerHand))
    {
        pokerText = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return pokerText;
}
```